# Xamarin.Ios BeingBackgroundTask parameters

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I'm trying this code from Xamarin. Ios documentation for background tasks: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/backgrounding/ios-backgrounding-techniques/ios-backgrounding-with-tasks. It says that the variable `taskId` in **line 6** has `CS0841: Cannot use local variable 'taskId' before it is declared`. How should I assign the `taskId`? Also, how do you declare `myFlag`? I cannot find any descriptions of how to use this variable.

```
Task.Factory.StartNew( () => {

    //expirationHandler only called if background time allowed exceeded
    var taskId = UIApplication.SharedApplication.BeginBackgroundTask(() => {
        Console.WriteLine("Exhausted time");
        UIApplication.SharedApplication.EndBackgroundTask(taskId); 
    });
    while(myFlag == true)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(UIApplication.SharedApplication.BackgroundTimeRemaining);
        myFlag = SomeCalculationNeedsMoreTime();
    }
    //Only called if loop terminated due to myFlag and not the expiration of time
    UIApplication.SharedApplication.EndBackgroundTask(taskId);
});
```

Comment: yeah and i got that fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the correct link  : [iOS Backgrounding with Tasks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/backgrounding/ios-backgrounding-techniques/ios-backgrounding-with-tasks) .

> How should I assign the taskId?

As it's mentioned in the link , `taskId` is a  unique identifier which returns from the registration process ,we just need to pass it when calling `EndBackgroundTask` .

```
nint taskID = UIApplication.SharedApplication.BeginBackgroundTask( () => {});
UIApplication.SharedApplication.EndBackgroundTask(taskId);
```

> how do you declare myFlag?

The variable just means the flag if ending the background task , just set it as `true` if you don't want to stop the task .

Comment: NOTE: The code in question is exact copy of one of the snippets on that doc page. [In section Avoiding App Termination With Expiration Handlers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/backgrounding/ios-backgrounding-techniques/ios-backgrounding-with-tasks#avoiding-app-termination-with-expiration-handlers). So it seems the doc page snippet is in error, won't even compile.